# android shows every time data in table

Tags: android, sqlite

I am developing a simple app.
app create a database & tables first.
then I want to find is there some data is available or not.

```
SQLiteDatabase db;
Cursor c;
TextView status;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    CreateDatabase();
    status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);
    checkData();

}

protected void CreateDatabase(){
    db=openOrCreateDatabase("AT", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS simData(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, sim_name VARCHAR,sim_number VARCHAR);");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS passwordData(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, password VARCHAR);");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS alternateData(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR,alternate_number VARCHAR);");

   db.execSQL("INSERT INTO simData (sim_name, sim_number) VALUES('user', '1111111')");

}
 protected void checkData(){
    openDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT id FROM simData";
    c = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    if(c ==null){
        String text = "Table is  Empty";
        Log.e("Table Operator","Table is Empty");
        status.setText(text);
    }else{
        String text = " data in table";
        Log.e("Table Operator","Some data in table");
        status.setText(text);
    }
}
protected void openDatabase(){
    db=openOrCreateDatabase("AT", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
}
```

if I remove this line and build again this time also android print else part

```
   db.execSQL("INSERT INTO simData (sim_name, sim_number) VALUES('user', '1111111')");
```

Comment: Why are you not using SqliteOpenHelper?

Comment: I am just started learning about android. so I want to use simple way @cricket-007.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database always has data after you insert once. If you comment the insert line, and re-run the app. The database still exists. That's the point of having a database...

However, if you uninstall the app, then rebuild and fix the condition

```
c.moveToFirst();  // reset the cursor 
if(c.getCount() <= 0){
    String text = "Table is  Empty";
```

Then, your else shouldn't be triggered

Comment: thanks, @cricket_007 to give me this statement. This is work